# With flutter redux is the StatefulWidget optional?

Tags: flutter

I would like to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux library in my Dart app and would like to know, if I use it, the `StatefulWidget` is becoming obsolet right?

Answer (score 0):

`StatefulWidget` is optional unless you need to use some mixins that you only use with a State object!, like `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` for animations